# Get a range of Documents in CosmosDB

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a collection with thousands of documents. Is there a way I can query the collection and return the first 500 documents? Then I want to load the next 500 documents (501-1000) and so on etc.

```
docDbClient.queryDocuments(collection._self, 'SELECT * FROM d ORDER BY d._ts DESC').toArray(function(error, arr) {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `skip` and `take` are not part of the query language today (though marked as "planned" on [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/6350987--documentdb-allow-paging-skip-take)), you'd need to come up with an alternative approach. Cosmos DB has built-in paging (with continuation tokens), which allows you to read a chunk of data at a time. You can specify the maximum item count per page, and then, as you're ready for the next page, perform the next read with the continuation token received from the previous read.

Or you can come up with your own scheme, perhaps based on some specific property you have.